# cURL error - cannot send text value for -d

Tags: json, windows, http, curl, nest-api

Executing:

```
curl.exe -k -L -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/[DEVICE_ID]/hvac_mode.json?auth=[ACCESS_TOKEN]" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "heat"
```

Produces the error:

```
{"error":"Invalid content sent"}
```

Using the exact same command but replacing `hvac_mode` with `target_temperature_f` and `"heat"` with `65` (any number will work and yes without quotes) works and the data changes upstream. I've tried sending `"heat"` without quotes and with '' instead of "" - no difference.

Permissions are good. [Documentation](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/api-overview/#hvac_mode) says I should be able to do this. I am currently in `"off"` `hvac_mode`.

If I replace `"heat"` with `'{"target_temperature_f": 73}'`, I get:

```
{"error":"Invalid content sent"}curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works in Linux:

```
curl.exe -k -L -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/[DEVICE_ID]?auth=[ACCESS_TOKEN]" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"hvac_mode":"heat"}'
```

and in Windows:

```
curl.exe -k -L -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/[DEVICE_ID]?auth=[ACCESS_TOKEN]" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"hvac_mode\":\"heat\"}"
```

Comment: It's not working with `hvac_mode` or `target_temperature_f` in that format. I've tried various combinations of switching `''` with `""` and vice versa. I get the same response as above each time.

Comment: It is working for me in exactly that format for hvac_mode and target_temperature_f although if I double quote the temperature value (eg '{"target_temperature_f":"60"}') then I get {"error":"value of 'target_temperature_f' is of wrong type"}, but avoiding the quotes fixes that. What platform are you on? I've tested on a Mac and a Pi

Comment: I am using windows. I've seen several other answers hinting towards the same usage yet I am unanimously getting the `{"error":"Invalid content sent"}`. I am using a batch file that echo's a variable that is populated with the command itself.

Comment: It doesn't like when I use `''` around the `{}` so I have been reverting to wrapping the whole things in `""` instead (URL's etc included).

Comment: OK, this works in Windows: -d "{\"hvac_mode\":\"heat\"}"

Comment: Still no luck. What curl binary did you try using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 and the curl.exe which comes with Git