# Wireshark not picking up cURL commands

Tags: windows, curl, wireshark

I am trying to debug an issue with cURL ([separate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26638731/1666510)) and even when I use a cURL command that successfully returns, I am getting nothing in wireshark. I am using the filter `http`. I am seeing other http traffic.

I should be seeing `HTTP/1.1 307`, `HTTP/1.1 200`, or even `HTTP/1.1 400` and I can for other things but not when I run a cURL command.

Comment: make sure wireshark is running as 'root', and check if you see any traffic without using filter 'http'. hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I am using windows (updated tags). I get huge amounts of traffic without any filter so a filter is necessary.

Comment: Ah! passed url contains `https` by any chance? try `port 443` filter.

Comment: @MayurPipaliya: Yes that did it! In my case I needed 443 and 9553, not http (assumes 80 I think). Post an answer for credit.

Comment: Wireshark cannot decode SSL-encrypted traffic, such as HTTPS, unless RSA encryption is used and you have access to the server's RSA private key. See the [documentation](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL). Try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) instead and configure cURL to use it as a proxy.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yeah unfortunately wireshark is not going to be as helpful as I'd thought in debugging the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: for curl, usually adding --trace-ascii is an easier way to fully trace what its doing than using wireshark...

Comment: Enigma, what was your Wireshark filter for this question, in order to narrow down curl requests?

Comment: See comment on selected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireshark has huge set of filters, but `http` filter only works for port 80.

So for custom port filters, use `port <port-no>`.

And for https, use `port 443`.

Check [decipher SSL traffic](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116557)* and [wireshark cheat sheet](http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/oct/18/cheat-sheets-tcpdump-and-wireshark/) for further exploration.

Comment: In my case I used the live filter `tcp.port == 9553 or tcp.port == 443` rather than the pre-capture filter.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to track curl packets is to use Fiddler.

Download and install .NET 4.0

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851

Then download and install Fiddler

http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4

Since Fiddler runs under port 8888, you need to open it up.

```
curl_setopt($proxyRequest, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'localhost:8888');
```

Then proceed with your curl request.

```
$proxyResult = curl_exec($proxyRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try listening to a different Input Capture Interface in Wireshark.

In my Wireshark I can click on a gear icon to select one or more Input Interfaces.  I was trying to listen for http and tcp on the `Wi-Fi En0` input interface, but all of my http and tcp requests were going through the `ppp0` input interface.  Once I selected the `ppp0`, and started a new capture then I was able to see the http and tcp packets.

For reference I am using Mac OSX.